# $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if $\{ x \} = \bigcap \{ \overline{U} : U \subseteq X\text{ is open}, x \in U \}$ for all $x \in X$

Tags: general-topology

I need help to prove the following:

> $X$ is a $T_2$-space iff for each $x\in X$ we have:
>   $$\{x\}=\bigcap\{\overline U\mid U\text{ is open in $X$ and $x\in U $}\}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider some $x \in X$. If $X$ is a $T_2$-space, then by definition for any $y \in X$ there exist neighbourhoods $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $y$ such that $U \cap V = \emptyset$. What does this tell you about the intersection of all the neighbourhoods of $x$?

Now suppose that $\{ x \} = \bigcap\{ \bar U\ |\ U \text{ is a neighbourhood of } x \}$ for every $x \in X$. If there existed a $y$ such that every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $y$ intersected non-trivially, what does this tell you about $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0):

$)\Longrightarrow$
In your notations, if $\bigcap \overline {U }\neq x$ then for each U exist $y\neq x$ such that $y\in U$ for each neithborhod of x. This is absurd.
$\Longleftarrow ($ 
If $\bigcap\overline { U}  = x$ then  for each $ y\neq x $ exist $U_x$ such that $y\not\in U_x$. Note that the equivalence holds with a T1 space.